# VS Code cpptools Debugging environment

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using `vscode` with `cpptools` from Microsoft. I've successfully attached the debugger (gdb) from the `launch.json` configuration to my project.

But I require to use the `"environment": []` array to setup my project so I can start a new debugging session from within vscode. But I don't know the usage syntax for that array and the documentation doesn't cover that part.

I've figured out of parsing errors reported by vscode the first element it `"Name"`. But what is the value tag? This at least doesn't work...

```
"environment": [
    {
        "Name":  "LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
        "Value": "/opt/mylibs",
    }
]
```

How Do I've to fill this variable? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. My initial example was almost correct but needed to be lowercase... like this:

```
"environment": [
    {
        "name":  "LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
        "value": "/opt/mylibs"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging suggests a format of

```
"env": {
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/mylibs"
},
```

Comment: hi. the problem is: `"env"` is an array and not an object. The parser won't accept that.

Answer (score 0):

In launch.vs.json, under the configurations, "env": { "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/your/path/to/lib" }